# Casting content on Google Chromecast: concrete and complete example

Tags: android, chromecast, google-cast

I'm searching for a concrete and complete example of an Application which cast some content Google Chromecast.

Something like [Android Training](http://developer.android.com/training/index.html) should be good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you seen the Google Developer docs for the [Android Cast SDK](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/android_sender)? The example there looks pretty concrete and they have various [example projects](https://github.com/googlecast).